# calling devise Registration create from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my devise

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def create 
 operation 1
 method 2
 ........
end
```

I want to call this Registration#create method from another controller

```
class XyzController <  ApplicationController

def custom_signup
    user = User.new(first_name: "xyz", last_name: "twr", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
    redirect_to user_registration_path(user)
end
```

I want to register a user in custom_signup method.
Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: is there a good reason why you need two different ways of registering?

Comment: You could put the `custom_signup` in `ApplicationController`

Comment: @AbM better, put it in a module in concerns and include into the two controllers where you need it. However, it's worth thinking about if you really need two ways of signing up